# Drop down menu or range slider for salary range filter?

Tags: user-expectation, ux-field, dropdown, range, price-range

We are filtering some job posts by their salary range, the range has definite steps (for instance $60K-$80K, $80K+, Up to $60K).

For filtering results which approach is better?

- Creating a salary range slider like what angel.co uses (as below)?
  [image]
- Createing a drop down menu based on definite ranges like below?

  - Up to $60K
  - $60K to $80K
  - $80K to $100K

In term of usability, user awareness and user expectation which of the above are better to implement?

Comment: related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45727/price-sliders-vs-range-links-as-a-faceted-search-form-element-for-filtering-on

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the number of steps you have, target domain of the application and familiarity of the users to use such sliders.

If there are many levels of segregation you allow, then putting that in a drop down would be cumbersome for the user to use it. On the other hand, if you have very few steps then sliders would not really slide per say. They would just be steppers.

I have no backing data, but I have personally never found sliders very usable. They look good for an E-Commerce site to narrow down the shirt you want to buy, but I rarely find myself using those. I would personally prefer a min-max textinput to quickly fill data and move along.

That is where the frequency of use and target domain comes to play. If I am designing something like a back office system and I am going to use it daily, then it will lose out on efficiency and quick operation. In such case even the drop down will lose out because data hiding.

These choices will bring their caveats, unless explicitly required, I will not recommend a slider. However, just to reiterate, this is personal opinion and I have no backing data.

Comment: The drop down is limited to 4 or 5 items at max, another issue that I insist on slider is that in drop down you are forced to scan until  youn find the range that you need, but in slider you are in the process, so it may decrease the bounce of use. whats your idea on this?

Comment: Drop downs should have limited options, true. But not 4-5. Considering for a salary bracket you can have well designed items which don't run to hundreds and thousands.

Sliders are beneficial when they can reflect the boundary values. I give you that.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an application for a wide range of customers I would definitely choose a verbose approach and a radio buttons group control. It gives you both fast accessibility, clear delimitations and a good view of the overall options.

[image]

Hope it helps you.